# Is there a module like lib2to3 that could update Python scripts written for 3.7 to be compatible with 3.12?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.7, python-3.12

I have over 100 scripts that are not compatible with 3.12. While technically possible to complete manually, this would be quite time intensive. Is there something like lib2to3 that can update these scripts in an automated fashion?

I can update them manually, but each script requires 30 minutes or so to update the methods and such.

Comment: The gap between Python 3.7 and 3.12 isn't nearly as large as the gap between Python 2.7 and Python 3 so there has been no demand for such an automated tool. Besides, I can't think of anything that would prevent scripts written for Python 3.7 from running in Python 3.12 except for the deprecation of a few minor functions here and there. Please clarify exactly what's preventing your Pythong 3.7 scripts from running in Python  3.12 so we can better help.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. You're probably right. It's more than just the python update. Selenium was updated, as well as several other modules. The way items are found on pages has changed with the structure of the find.by and other things like that. Even setting up the browser has changed. That's one bit that needs updating through many of the scripts, but there's probably several other big things through them. (these are generally regression type scripts that test websites and backend services, but also interact with other gui applications as well using pyautogui and others.

Comment: I see. In that case what you need is a refactoring tool, with custom refactoring rules tailored to your specific requirements. I recommend that you take a look at the excellent [`refactor`](https://refactor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module. Feel free to ask about the usage of the module in a separate question if you are stuck making a refactoring rule that works for you.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds exactly like what I need... If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as such.